# A safe subset of CSS?

Tags: css

Addressing all the browsers back to IE6 is quite challenging. Every browser supports different features of the specifications. Is there a guide on a safe subset of CSS which can be used across browsers (IE6,IE7,FF1,FF2,Safari,Opera)? That way I wouldn't have to test my style sheets in 6 different browsers after every small modification - and adjust to their irritating quirks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a valuable reference.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Also, for IE and select other browsers - conditional comments.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx

I use them this way.  I override any IE specifics.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" />
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme-ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Can't get enough of quirksmode.org, so useful for figuring out compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience while some CSS attributes might be supported by all browsers they don't always behave the same.  Even some of the most basic attributes, like margin/padding/float, can cause things to look different between IE and everything else.

Usually the overall site template is the most complex.  The way I do things is once I get that template written, and the simple classes to be used by the actual content, test a few sample pages in all the browsers.  Usually you won't throw any major wrenches in the system once you're just working on content (although I'll always do a paranoid check here and there).

Answer (score 2):

Both links from Daniel and jleedev are valuable resources. Your best bet in many cases is to use a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (just one example) that will minimize the rendering differences between browsers.

Dean Edward's [IE7](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) is a JavaScript include that will add many standard CSS functionality into IE6/7 (such as `<abbr>` and support for pseudo selectors).

I recommend developing for Firefox/Opera/W3 spec, then using conditional comments for IE6/7.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a book called **Pro CSS and HTML Design Patterns**, which contains pre-tested snippets of reusable CSS. This is very close to what I actually needed.